# robot state publisher error

Tags: urdf, robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am learning ROS tutorial (Building a Visual Robot Model with URDF from Scratch) and when I rum this command

roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=01-myfirst.urdf

I got following result.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81716/robot-state-publisher-error/) by [wafeeq](https://answers.ros.org/users/6400/wafeeq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-09-20

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wafeeq](https://answers.ros.org/users/6400/wafeeq/) on 2013-09-20**:
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [robot_state_publisher/state_publisher]: robot_state_publisher
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/wafeeq/catkin_ws/src/pr2_common
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/hydro/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/hydro/share
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/hydro/stacks

**Comment by [wafeeq](https://answers.ros.org/users/6400/wafeeq/) on 2013-09-20**:
I have also installed robot_state_publisher but it could not find state_publisher a node of it.

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [robot_state_publisher/state_publisher]: can't locate node [state_publisher] in package [robot_state_publisher]

**Comment by [wafeeq](https://answers.ros.org/users/6400/wafeeq/) on 2013-09-21**:
Can anybody help me please?

**Comment by [cstew](https://answers.ros.org/users/14231/cstew/) on 2014-04-28**:
I'm trying to incorporate gazebo_ros_control plugin in my own urdf and starting by just putting a controller on a single joint. I keep getting the same error saying "cannont launch node of this type..."  ros-hydro-robot-state-publisher installed.  Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have ros-hydro-robot-state-publisher installed?

If not, try

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-robot-state-publisher
```

---

Originally posted by [mortonjt](https://answers.ros.org/users/4408/mortonjt/) with karma: 217 on 2013-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wafeeq](https://answers.ros.org/users/6400/wafeeq/) on 2013-09-22**:
wow great it worked. But I had also installed robot_state_publisher manually but it did not work. thanks

**Comment by [sujeet](https://answers.ros.org/users/36611/sujeet/) on 2018-07-23**:
When I tried to run the commanded, it gave me the following error.
**E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-robot-state-publisher**
Is there a way to fix this issue?

**Comment by [wmbolle](https://answers.ros.org/users/53474/wmbolle/) on 2020-04-12**:
You probably have to adapt to your version of ROS. For me, it is ros-melodic-robot-state-publisher. You should be able to find the right package name via apt-cache search robot-state-publisher.